# PHP - move_uploaded_file not working to copy file in same folder

Tags: php, file-upload

Having some trouble with rewriting a photo file. I need the file name to get rewritten as a random string. The file uploads fine - I can't seem to get it copy the file and rewrite the file name to the random string. The file is going to stay in the directory.

The function is working fine and I can rewrite file name in the database, but it will not rewrite the actual file in the folder. The folder permissions are rwxr-xr-x (755).

Any thoughts?

```
function AfterUpdate(){
    $file = $this->file_attachment;
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $newFilename = $path_parts['dirname'] . "/" . uniqid() . "." . $path_parts['extension'];

    $file_src = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file; 
    $newfile_src = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $newFilename; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($file_src, $newfile_src)){
        $this->file_attachment = $newFilename;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `/` between `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  and `$file`

Comment: Thanks, but $file is "/upload/photo.jpeg" so the "/" is already there.

Answer (score 0):

`$newFilename` contains a path location I guess by looking at the `$path_parts['dirname'] . "/" . uniqid() . "." . $path_parts['extension'];`.

`$newFilename` should just be the new file name with extension.
`move_uploaded_file` will only move files from one folder to another or the same, that already exists. But will not create a folder for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. Replace `move_uploaded_file` with `rename`. The file will not be moved, just renamed.

```
    $file = $this->file_attachment;
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $newFilename = $path_parts['dirname'] . "/" . uniqid() . "." . $path_parts['extension'];

    $file_src = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $file; 
    $newfile_src = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $newFilename; 
    if (rename($file_src, $newfile_src)){
        $this->file_attachment = $newFilename;
    }
```